# Send request to server Using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi i am trying to send request and want to hit my url on button click but it is not working

updated code

```
    <script>
$(function(){

      $("#submit").click(function(){
var sms="url/sendmessage.php?user=""&password="&mobile=7828208357&message=hello&sender=&type=3INFORM";

    $.ajax({        
        url: sms ,
        data: "message=",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (resp) {
            alert(resp);
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error: '+e);
        }  
    });
      });

});
</script>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

Here given url i want to hit on button click How can i achieve this

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you actually missed the escape characters for quotes in the url or its just a typo here?

Comment: What is happening?  Do you get to the click event, do you get an error, is your web service on the same domain as your code here, do you have a cross domain issue?  please provide further detail

Comment: i am not getting any error and my web service is on same domain

Answer (score 0):

```
var sms="url/sendmessage.php?user=""&password="&mobile=7828208357&message=hello&sender=&type=3INFORM";
```

in this part of your code you should escape quotation marks like:

```
var sms="url/sendmessage.php?user=\"\"&password=\"&mobile=7828208357&message=hello&sender=&type=3INFORM";
```

Comment: user="" is blank only in stackover flow i have full url and providing value in my code  where "" is available

Comment: The content of "" is not important, anyway the quotes themselves must be escaped because you started your string with ", so try this solution